# What happens to PPA and applications installed from PPA if Ubuntu is updated to the next release

Tags: package-management, ppa

What happens to PPA and applications installed from PPA if Ubuntu is updated to the next release? Since Ubuntu-provided repositories are specific to Ubuntu releases, I'm guessing the same is for PPA? But only a URL for a PPA is provided--how do I know if the PPA is compatible with my Ubuntu release?

Essentially, what do I need to do in regard to PPA and applications installed from PPA when I update to the next Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPAs and other third-party repositories are disabled during a release upgrade. You have to manually enable them post-upgrade.

The packages are upgraded if a newer version exists, or left alone if there's no corresponding package in the official repositories.

You can visit the PPA page and check if it supports the newer release. In the *Overview of published packages* section, the *Published in* dropdown menu lists the  releases for which packages are available.

Comment: After having had a LOT of problems (with a dangerous PPA, I admit, touching basic parts of the system --- the X server in my case) I really advise to  [purge](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed) all your PPAs before upgrading, and reinstall them afterward. I have scripts to list all your installed PPA and the packages installed from them, so that the reinstall is fast.

Answer (score 0):

Trusty and Utopic have this problem.  Most PPAs have support for both.  But what if you dont have a PPA that supports trusty but not Utopic, you would simply uninstall the application by typing in a Terminal

`sudo apt-get autoremove packagename`
`apt-get update`

It is completely up to the maintainer if they wanted to support anything past Trusty.

In terms of how to remove PPAs
`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:whatever/ppa`

Also see this [answer for PPA removals.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed)
It explains how to remove PPAs in other formats than just the Terminal command.